# Can I evaluate an argument in a subsequent function call?

Tags: r, lazy-evaluation

Is it possible to evaluate a function argument in a subsequent function call multiple times, when the value that I try to capture may change inside the mother function?

The problem I have is similar to the example below.
I have a mother function `f1()` with a child function `rnorm()` inside a `for` loop.
The child function should receive a different argument in each iteration of the loop (i.e., `rnorm(n = ii)`, but I want to control this at the level of the mother function.

```r
f1 <- function(I, n = 1) {

    res <- vector("list", length = I)

    for (ii in seq_len(I)) {
        res[[ii]] <- rnorm(n = n)
    }
    return(res)
}

f1(I = 2, n = 1)
f1(I = 2, n = ii) # desired, but obviously doesn't work
```

I tried to play around with `eval()`, `quote()`, `get()`, etc. but to no avail.

Comment: I don't get what you really want to do. Why using `rnorm(n = ii)` in the loop is not ok?

Comment: Because sometimes I want to call `f1(n = 10)` and sometimes `f1(n = ii)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want non-standard evaluation, which means you need to modify the expression based on a function parameter (typically using `substitute`) before it is evaluated.

```
f1 <- function(I, n = 1) {

  nval <- substitute(n)


  res <- vector("list", length = I)

  if (is.numeric(nval)) {
    for (ii in seq_len(I)) {
      res[[ii]] <- rnorm(n = n)
    }
  } 

  if (is.name(nval)) {
    for (ii in seq_len(I)) {
      res[[ii]] <- eval(substitute(rnorm(n = nval), list(nval = nval)))
    }
  }

  return(res)
}

f1(I = 2, n = 1)
#[[1]]
#[1] 0.4600974
#
#[[2]]
#[1] -0.6399949

f1(I = 2, n = ii)
#[[1]]
#[1] 0.4554501
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 0.7048373 1.0351035
```

I think your example is just poor software design. I strongly advise against doing it.

A much better approach would be this:

```
f1 <- function(I, n) {

  res <- vector("list", length = I)

  if (missing(n)) {
    for (ii in seq_len(I)) {
      res[[ii]] <- rnorm(n = ii)
    }
  } else {
    for (ii in seq_len(I)) {
      res[[ii]] <- rnorm(n = n)
    }
  }

  return(res)
}

f1(I = 2, n = 1)
f1(I = 2)
```